# Como faço para instalar outro site Wordpress usando Docker-compose?

Tags: wordpress, instalador, docker

Eu fiz a instalação do **Wordpress** dentro de um **container** no Ubuntu 18.04 lts, através deste [tutorial aqui](https://www.hostinger.com.br/tutoriais/como-instalar-wordpress-no-docker-windows-macos-e-linux/#gref). Funcionou.

Agora, gostaria de instalar mais de um site Wordpress pra criar outros projetos diferentes.

Como posso fazer isso? Devo criar outro container? Criar outro arquivo e fazer o mesmo procedimento do tutorial?

Estou perdido, me ajudem, por favor.

Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para criar um novo container com a aplicação wordpress você precida duplicar as configuração abaixo da tag "wordpress" no seu arquivo do docker-compose. Lembrando que você vai precisar alterar algumas configurações, como a porta que o seu container wordpress irá utilizar e o banco de dados

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde,

Sim, cada container do Docker roda apenas um projeto por vez. Nesse caso, o melhor seria criar outro projeto e colocar Docker nele.

Para cada projeto, um container Docker deverá ser criado para utilizá-lo.

Abraço.

Comment: Obrigado, Leonardo! 
Se não for pedir muito, saberia me dizer como faço para criar outro container? Eu só consegui renomear o primeiro, mas para criar outro me pede um login, não entendi direito, ou se souber de algum tutorial para me indicar? Obrigado novamente.

Comment: https://www.hostinger.com.br/tutoriais/como-instalar-wordpress-no-docker-windows-macos-e-linux/#gref

Comment: https://www.mundodevops.com/instalando-e-configurando-o-wordpress-utilizando-o-docker/

Comment: http://blog.aeciopires.com/instalando-o-wordpress-via-docker/

Comment: Perfeito! Muito obrigado pela disposição e ajuda!